# Circular Motion Question - 11th Grade

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

I have been recently solving physics questions since I have an exam next week. I came up across the following question and I have been trying for a good amount of hours to solve this question.

The problem: I get an impossible acceleration value that's stand around $9474 m/s^{-2}$.

The question:

> An object with $0.3kg$ mass is attached with two ropes as described in the following picture, and he is moving in horizontal circle motion. The frequency is $10$ spins/sec.

Information given in the question:
$f = 10 Hz$
mass = $0.3kg$

Sorry for my bad English, I am not a native speaker. The question is originally in Hebrew, so I had to translate it. I tried my best hopefully somebody can help .

The following image:
[image]

Comment: *impossible acceleration value* Why do you think it is impossible?

Comment: I think that this problem was discussed previously on this SE.

Comment: Can you show how you get  the impossible acceleration?

Comment: @G.Smith I thought it's impossible since I wasn't too sure if it's possible to reach that high acceleration. I was wrong, thanks for your reply.

Comment: @nasu 
you have the frequency = 10 HZ
Then you can get the speed of angle (I guess that's how you call it) = 2pi * f = 20pi 1/sec
R = 3 * sin(53) ~= 2.4m

Now since I got all of that I just did a = v^2/r 
which equals to w^2 * r ~= 9474 meter/sec^2

Comment: @nasu "Check my calculation" questions are off-topic here. OTOH, calculations may occur during the course of a *conceptual* question related to a homework-like exercise. But yes, the OP's calculation is correct. ;)

Comment: The angular frequency is 2 •62.8. I don't understand what your value is.  The radius looks right.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to calculate a sine. You have a right triangle, so the product of the 2 sides equals the product of the hypotenuse & the altitude: 3×4 = (12/5)×5.

Comment: @PM 2Ring He showed his work in comments.  And the question is actually about the "impossibility" of the value.

Comment: It's OK.  Don't worry.  Yes, the question could be improved with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you checked your work and found out that the value is probably right,  your question may come from comparing this with g.  It is understandable to ask yourself if the answer makes sense.  It is actually recommendable.  You should note that centripetal accelerations encountered in common situations can be much larger than g.  Just try to estimate the centripetal acceleration of the points on the rim of a car tire at usual speed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I really appreciate the time you have putted in to answer my question. That's mainly why I got so confused of that value, but I was wrong. I wish I could up-vote your answer sadly I am a new user. Also, I want to thank everyone for the comments.

Comment: I am glad it helped.  I am happy to help students asking questions.  There are not too many.  Don't worry about up-voting.

Answer (score 0):

With more accurate angles, the radius of the circular path is 2.4 m. At ten cycles/sec that gives a tangential speed of 150.8 m/sec.  Your centripetal acceleration is correct. With that and the mass, you could find the tension in each rope.